# python change starting up/default directory

Tags: python, directory, python-2.7

I am new to python. 
Every time I start the shell, it always gives me directory as:

> ".../file name/Python/"

But I want to change it to:

> ".../file name/python program/"

How do I do it without changing the import modulate stuff?
I am afraid to make it wrong so that I can't import anymore, but it is so annoy to put:

```
import os
os.chdir(".../file name/python program/")
```

every time after I open the shell.
Thanks for help!

Comment: just start python from the directory you want it to be? Or are you using some kind of shortcut?

Comment: I am using IDLE shell and I am using shortcut that is coming from the directory of ".../file name/Python/".

Comment: for imports you should probably be using pythonpath anyway ... but yeah just open the shell in the folder where you want cwd to be

Comment: will that influence the import stuff?
and please if you can, make an answer, so I can accept if it is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout:  http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP

This is an environment variable that can be set to a file. This is executed prior to start up of shell and only applies if you are using interactive shell.

You can use this to specify a path as current directory at start of your shell.

```
import os
os.chdir('/pathto')
del os
```

Write to a file and point to it with env variable.

If this is just specific to a file that you are running, then you should be changing the directory inside the script

```
os.chdir('/pathto')
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.
Thanks for the edition. BTW how do you change the plain text into python code?

Comment: @windsound: I could not get you. Python code is also plain text but interpreted by a python interpreter.

Comment: Bcz my original quesiton is all plain text. But after your edition, some of my question part becomes python code with colors. How do you do that?

Comment: @windsound: When you are writing in Edit mode in Stackoverflow. Above the editor, you will see an icon marked "{}". Select all your code and click it. Or simply type your code with 4 spaces on the left.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set up python so that it will automatically search in a specific directory on your computer when you import modules, open to your /python27/Lib/site.py file and add your paths to the PREFIXES list near the top of the file