# PYTHON-changing start up directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I start my python shell,it starts in a particular directory. I want to change it to some other directory. So that whenever I open the python shell again in future, it opens in the new set directory.

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: How do you open a python shell? (Yes, silly question, but an important detail)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python change starting up/default directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905094/python-change-starting-up-default-directory)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like, presuming Unix like system.

Set up PYTHONSTARTUP script to be run when starting Python REPL.

```
$ export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonrc
```

Create python script in $HOME/.pythonrc

```
# file: ~/.pythonrc
# I always want to start python in my Projects dir.
import os
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Projects"))
```

Test it in python REPL.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'<<YOUR_HOME>>/Projects'
```

You could change it to suite your specific needs but in general it does the right thing.